# How do I add the 4 bit full adders and 4:1 mux together?

Tags: vhdl, quartus

//this is the 4:1 mux

```
Library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 

ENTITY fourMux IS
PORT(B : IN BIT_VECTOR (0 to 3);
sel : IN BIT_VECTOR(0 to 1);
clk : IN BIT;
output : OUT BIT);
END fourMux;

ARCHITECTURE example OF fourMux IS
BEGIN
PROCESS (clk)
    VARIABLE temp : BIT;
    BEGIN
        IF(clk = '1') THEN
            IF sel = "00" THEN
                temp := B (0);
            ELSIF sel = "01" THEN
                temp := B (1);
            ELSIF sel = "10" THEN
                temp := B (2);
            ELSE
                temp := B (3);
            END IF;
            output <= temp AFTER 5ns;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;
END example;
```

// this is the full adder

```
Library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 


entity fullAdders is
port(x,y,Cin :in std_logic; 
        sum, Cout:out std_logic);
end fullAdders;


architecture level of fullAdders is
begin 
    sum <= (x xor y xor Cin); 
    Cout <= (x and y) or (x and Cin) or (x and Cin); 
end level;
```

// fourbit adder

```
entity Fourbit is
port(a,b :in bit_vector(3 downto 0); 
        Cin :in bit; 
        Cout, sum :out bit); 
end Fourbit;

architecture struct of Fourbit is
component fullAdders
    port(x,y,Cin :in bit; 
            Cout, sum :out bit);
end component; 

component fourMux
     port( A,B,C,D : in STD_LOGIC;
            S0,S1: in STD_LOGIC;
            Z: out STD_LOGIC);
end component;
```

This is what I have so far. and I am confused about to use my fourMux with the full adder? any suggestion? What do I do from here? I try using port map from the componet but it didnt work.

Comment: You're missing some information. What is the multiplexer supposed to do? You can gang four adders together into a four bit adder by instantiating them (possibly using a generate statement) There are examples on Stackoverflow. Note your declared entities have port types of bit and bit vector and four mux has port types of std_logic, they aren't compatible. If this is school work please share your instructions.

Comment: You are using a clock signal as latch enable. This is bad design practice. Either you describe an combinational MUX or a properly registered MUX.